# What is the meaning of “In case the talents will be ignored, a person may take one step back and thus get a Karmic Debt.”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

In the paragraph below, the meaning of boldfaced line isn't clear.

> Power brings responsibility and freedom to choose. In case of acting responsibly and using lofty powers, a powerful person will find reward in choice itself. **In case the talents will be ignored, a person may take one step back and thus get a Karmic Debt.**

Any interpretations please?

Comment: What is the source of this passage?  It is not quite correct English, plus it seems to reference previous statements that explain what things like "one step back' and "Karmic Debt" mean to the writer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says that if the person that holds that much power ignores the talents (acting responsibly, for example), that person would go back in her/his life's progression (take one step back) and bear the weight of this action for a really long time (Karmic Debt. Debt is something that you owe to somebody, and Karmic is derived from Karma, which is what you inherit from past lives or the consequences of your actions).